# select e insert en store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos select en "cascada":
select 1:

```
SELECT a.cod_almacen, a.id_almacen 
FROM almacen a 
INNER JOIN grupos g ON a.cod_almacen = g.centro_costo 
ORDER BY a.id_almacen
```

Para todos los almacenes:
select 2:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9) as begins, 
u.group_identifier,  
u.identifier, 
u.user_profile, 
u.user_scheduler,   
e.cargo,  
t.description, 
t.start_hour, 
t.end_hour, 
t.break_minutes,  
ROUND(md.meta_diaria, 2) as meta_diaria 
FROM usuarios as u  
    INNER JOIN planificacion as p ON u.identifier = p.identifier 
    INNER JOIN turnos_ as t ON t.id_shift = p.hashed_shift_id 
    INNER JOIN empleado as e ON REPLACE(e.cod_empleado, '-', '')  =  u.identifier 

OUTER APPLY (SELECT sum(venta) as meta_diaria 
     FROM venta as v  
    WHERE v.id_calendario = SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9) 
    -- AND v.id_almacen = a.id_almacen 
     AND v.id_almacen = select1.id_almacen  
     AND tipo = 'PPTO' ) AS md
WHERE p.begins >= 20190701000000 AND p.begins <= 20190705000000
  AND u.group_identifier = 'select1.cod_almacen' 
 AND u.enabled = 1 
 ORDER BY begins, identifier ASC;
```

De éste segundo select obtengo los campos a insertar en una nueva tabla:

```
 INSERT INTO metas (id_calendario, cod_almacen, cargo, horas_turno, monto_meta_dia, monto_meta_cargo, total_horas) 
                    VALUES (select2.begins, select2.group_identifier, select2.cargo, select2.horas, select2.meta_diaria, select2.meta, select2.total_horas_d)
```

Actualmente estoy haciendo todo ésto en php pero se tarda demasiado y necesito colocar todo éste proceso dentro de un store procedure pero no entiendo muy bien cómo hacer ésto.
Las consultas las tengo por separado porque necesito agrupar los resultados del select 2 para cada almacen.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando con tu pregunta de ayer, se podría tener una sola instrucción de la siguiente manera.

```
INSERT INTO metas (id_calendario, cod_almacen, cargo, horas_turno, monto_meta_dia, monto_meta_cargo, total_horas) 
SELECT SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9) as begins, 
    u.group_identifier,
    e.cargo,  
    DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60)  as horas,
    ROUND(md.meta_diaria, 2) as meta_diaria,
    md.meta_diaria / SUM( CASE WHEN u.user_profile <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9)) AS fraccion_meta,   
    SUM( CASE WHEN u.user_profile <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9)) AS total_horas_dia
FROM usuarios               AS u  
INNER JOIN planificacion    AS p ON u.identifier = p.identifier 
INNER JOIN turnos_          AS t ON t.id_shift = p.hashed_shift_id 
INNER JOIN empleado         AS e ON REPLACE(e.cod_empleado, '-', '')  =  u.identifier
INNER JOIN almacen          AS a ON u.group_identifier = a.cod_almacen
OUTER APPLY (SELECT sum(venta) as meta_diaria 
     FROM venta as v  
    WHERE v.id_calendario = SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9) 
    -- AND v.id_almacen = a.id_almacen 
     AND v.id_almacen = select1.id_almacen  
     AND tipo = 'PPTO' ) AS md
WHERE p.begins >= 20190701000000 AND p.begins <= 20190705000000
 AND u.enabled = 1 
 ORDER BY begins, identifier ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

No veía la manera de unir los dos selects, hasta que por fin entendí como hacerlo. Luego, para obtener los registros e insertarlos en la tabla que necesito, hice un insert into select

```
USE [BBDD]
GO

 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 -- =============================================
 -- Author:     <Author,,Name>
 -- Create date: <Create Date,,>
 -- Description:    Calcular las metas de ventas por cargo, por dia, por almacen
 -- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_calcular_metas]  
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@fechaini varchar(14),
@fechafin varchar(14) 
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO metas( id_calendario, cod_almacen, cargo, horas_turno, monto_meta_dia, semana_nro, monto_meta_cargo, total_horas, meta_semanal )
SELECT SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9) as begins, 
        u.group_identifier,  
        e.cargo, 
        DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) as horas,
        ROUND(md.meta_diaria, 2) as meta_diaria, 
        c.semana_bono, 
        (ROUND(md.meta_diaria, 2) / SUM( CASE WHEN cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9), al.id_almacen) ) * ( DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) ) as meta,  
        SUM( CASE WHEN cargo <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9), al.id_almacen) AS total_horas_dia,  
        ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN cargo = 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN md.meta_diaria END) OVER(PARTITION BY semana_bono, al.id_almacen), 2) as meta_semanal 

    FROM usuarios as u 
        INNER JOIN planificacion as p ON u.identifier = p.identifier 
        INNER JOIN turnos_ as t ON t.id_shift = p.hashed_shift_id 
        INNER JOIN empleado as e ON REPLACE(e.cod_empleado, '-', '') = u.identifier 
        INNER JOIN calendario as c ON c.id_calendario = CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9))  
        INNER JOIN almacen as al ON al.cod_almacen = u.group_identifier 
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT sum(venta) as meta_diaria 
                        FROM DWBadamaxRetail.fact.venta as v 
                        WHERE v.id_calendario = SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9) AND v.id_almacen = al.id_almacen AND tipo = 'PPTO' ) AS md 

    WHERE p.begins >= @fechaini  
            AND p.begins <= @fechafin  
            AND u.enabled = 1 

    ORDER BY begins, group_identifier ASC;

 END
```